# Why should runtime implementers avoid enumerating EnumerableStorageMap storage entries on-chain?

Tags: rust, substrate

The documentation for [`EnumerableStorageMap`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support/storage/trait.EnumerableStorageMap.html) states:

> Primarily useful for off-chain computations. Runtime implementors should avoid enumerating storage entries on-chain.

Why should runtime implementers avoid enumerating these storage entries on-chain?

Answer (score 0):

In runtime development, list iteration is, generally speaking, evil.

Unless explicitly guarded against, it will add unbounded O(N) complexity to an operation that will only charge O(1) fees. As a result, your chain becomes attackable.

Additionally, if lists become so large, and you iterate over all the elements, the process may take longer than the block time, and thus a node would never produce a block.

You will find bounded loops within certain Runtime modules, but you need to be conscious of the time/computation complexity of those loops.

You can easily "simulate" an enumerable list with two storage items:

```
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as Example {
        AllPeopleArray get(person): map u32 => T::AccountId;
        AllPeopleCount get(num_of_people): u32;
    }
}
```

But I believe the intention is to make it a little more difficult for you to do bad things within your modules.

Comment: Thanks, so if a stubborn runtime implementer only wants their  operation to run on-chain, but wants to minimise associated risks, could they just take the following actions?
1) Discourage blockchain attacks by attaching a bond amount to calling the operation to cover the maximum possible execution cost;
2) Ensure the node continues block production by preventing runtime upgrades that extend the default block time, and testing that the operation doesn't exceed it.